# How to fire an event everytime CheckBox.IsChecked is assigned a value?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am facing the following problem: for a checkbox in WPF I need to know, when an attempt was made to change the state of the checkbox, i.e.:

- if checkbox was clicked by the user - fire an event,
- if checkbox IsChecked property was given a new value - fire an event,
- if checkbox IsChecked property was given the same value as it already has - fire an event.

This construction is to be used in a piece of software that controls an embedded device. It is not possible to request the state of this device, it is only possible to tell to the device to enter certain state. If the device is in certain state, telling it again to enter this state makes no harm. Hence, my request.

Up to now, I've come up with the following solution: write a new class which derives from CheckBox, but redefine IsChecked property in the following way:

```
public class ExtendedCheckBox : CheckBox
{
    public class IsCheckedAssignedEventArgs : RoutedEventArgs
    {
        public bool? prevState { get; set; }
        public bool? newState { get; set; }
        public IsCheckedAssignedEventArgs(bool? prevState, bool? newState)
        {
            this.prevState = prevState;
            this.newState = newState;
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler IsCheckedAssigned = delegate { };

    public new bool? IsChecked
    {
        get
        {
            return base.IsChecked;
        }

        set
        {
            this.IsCheckedAssigned(this, new IsCheckedAssignedEventArgs(this.IsChecked, value));
            base.IsChecked = value;
        }
    }
}
```

It works well only if the IsChecked property is assigned programmatically. The event is not fired, when the CheckBox is clicked.

The first question is - is this the correct approach for my problem? 
If yes, how to make it work for all cases I need?
If no, what is a better approach?

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: how are you binding your IsChecked ?

Comment: Instead of implementing your own checkbox I'd rather listen on the `Checked` and `Unchecked` events, is this not possible for your use case?

Comment: @nit, I am not binding it at the moment.

Comment: @Matten - listening to Checked and Unchecked is not an option. If the checkbox is checked and I set programmatically IsChecked = true, no event is fired.

Comment: WPF is designed to use the MVVM pattern, and setting the value programmatic on the model will also update the state of the databound checkbox, given you have implementet INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IsChecked property on `CheckBox` is a `DependancyProperty`. Just creating a new wrapper over it is not going to update it via UI as WPF engine will call the `GetValue`() and `SetValue`() to get and set its value not your property wrappers.

If you want to just get to know if you IsChecked is changed then you can override the propertymeta data for IsCheckedProperty by adding below code in your class.

```
    static ExtendedCheckBox ()
    {
        IsCheckedProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ExtendedCheckBox ), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null , new CoerceValueCallback(IsCheckedCoerced)));
    }

    private static object IsCheckedCoerced(DependencyObject obj, object value)
    {
        var myCheckBox = obj as ExtendedCheckBox ;

        if (myCheckBox != null)
        {
            myCheckBox.IsCheckedAssigned(myCheckBox, new IsCheckedAssignedEventArgs(myCheckBox.IsChecked, (bool)value));
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: If I combine it with my current solution, it works. However, if I assign a new value which causes the state to actually change, the event is fired twice, once on my new IsChecked assignment, second time on the OverrideMetadata. This is what I would like to avoid.

Comment: you dont need IsChecked property now in your code... you can directly set the checkbox IsChecked now

Comment: No, if IsChecked is set to true (checkbox is checked) and I set it to true again (programmatically), nothing happens. And I need an event also then.

Comment: then you will have to set the CoerceValueCallBack instead of PropertyChagned like in updated answer

Comment: It works like a charm. Thank you very much.
I have only one remark - now the event is fired before the IsChecked property is changed (if it needs changing). The type of the action must be determined by testing the EventArgs parameters.

Answer (score 1):

if you databind to the property IsChecked it will set the value on your bind target every time it is changed

Answer (score 0):

I am using checkbox something like below in my project

```
<CheckBox Name="chkExist" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Content="Existing settings" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding IsExistingSetting, Mode=TwoWay}"></CheckBox>

bool isExistingSetting;

public bool IsExistingSetting
{
  get { return isExistingSetting; }
  set
  {
    if (value != isExistingSetting)
    {
     //calling one method as per my business. Method(value);
      isExistingSetting= value;
      OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
     }
    }
 }
 private void Method(bool isValue)
 {
  if(isValue)
  {
    // do something...
  }
  else
  {
   // do something...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override OnClick ; OnChecked and OnUnchecked events in your class and raise your new event;

Comment: No, OnClick is fired only when checkbox is changed with mouse or keyboard, OnChecked and OnUnchecked are fired if the state is actually changed. I also need an event, when the state might not be changed.